# Calculate delta in dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries which hold list of tuples like this:

```
mydict:{'A1':{'week1': [(1,1,34),(1,2,3),(1,3,10),(2,1,3),(2,2,9)...()],
              'week2': [(1,1,4),(1,2,11),(1,3,8),(2,1,5),(2,2,7)...()],
               ...
              'week19': [(1,1,12),(1,2,13),(1,3,32),(2,1,45),(2,2,15)...()],
              'week20': [(1,1,43),(1,2,30),(1,3,6),(2,1,7),(2,2,4)...()]}
        'A2':{'week1': [(1,1,6),(1,2,4),(1,3,2),(2,1,87),(2,2,32)...()],
              'week2': [(1,1,32),(1,2,15),(1,3,43),(2,1,2),(2,2,12)...()],
               ...
              'week20': [(1,1,3),(1,2,3),(1,3,16),(2,1,17),(2,2,11)...()]}
               ...
 }
```

I would like to calculate the delta of the third items (which their first two items are identical) in each tuple inside of the dictionaries, between each week (e.g., week1 and week2,.. week19 and week20)and put them as new dictionaries in the main dictionary. So my desired outcome could be like this:

```
    out_dict:{'A1':{'week1': [(1,1,34),(1,2,3),(1,3,10),(2,1,3),(2,2,9)...()],
              'week2': [(1,1,4),(1,2,11),(1,3,8),(2,1,5),(2,2,7)...()],
                ...
              'week19': [(1,1,12),(1,2,13),(1,3,32),(2,1,45),(2,2,15)...()],
              'week20': [(1,1,43),(1,2,30),(1,3,6),(2,1,7),(2,2,4)...()],
              'delta_wk1_wk2':[(1,1,30),(1,2, 8),(1,3,2),(2,1,2),(2,2,2)...()],
              'delta_wk20_wk19':[(1,1,31),(1,2, 23),(1,3,26),(2,1,38),(2,2,11)...()]
              ...
   }
        'A2':{'week1': [(1,1,6),(1,2,4),(1,3,2),(2,1,87),(2,2,32)...()],
              'week2': [(1,1,32),(1,2,15),(1,3,43),(2,1,2),(2,2,12)...()],
              ...
              'week19': [(1,1,7),(1,2,0),(1,3,2),(2,1,33),(2,2,10)...()],
              'week20': [(1,1,3),(1,2,3),(1,3,16),(2,1,17),(2,2,11)...()]}
               ...
              'delta_wk1_wk2':[(1,1,26),(1,2, 11),(1,3,41),(2,1,85),(2,2,20)...()],
              'delta_wk20_wk19':[(1,1,4),(1,2, 3),(1,3,14),(2,1,14),(2,2,1)...()]
 }
```

Comment: You mean between each week and the next? Did you try anything you want to share?

Comment: Is the list of tuples sorted and is for every first two tuple entries one in the next week?
What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes, e.g., between week1 and week2, week2 and week3, week3 and week4, and so on. No, actually I could not find a way to start.

Comment: The tuples are sorted.

Comment: Would you also need delta_wk2_wk3 or are you doing this in pairs - i.e. delta_wk1_wk2 then delta_wk3_wk4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get each pair of weeks, you can use a pairwise iterator, which you can look at the itertools recipes to see the implementation; it looks like this:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    x, y = tee(iterable)
    next(y, None)
    return zip(x, y)
```

Then you can use that on an entry of your dictionary:

```
def add_deltas(data):
    for first, second in pairwise(data.keys()):
        deltas = []
        for a, b in zip(data[first], data[second]):
            if b:
                deltas.append((a[0], a[1], abs(a[2] - b[2])))
        data[f'delta_{first}_{second}'] = deltas
```

Use this to loop through your dictionary:

```
for v in mydict.values():
    add_deltas(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I can understand, this is a solution using Numpy, since it's tagged.

I'm using just the `A1` group of weeks with a little variation to show a sorting problem:

```
data = {
    'week8': [(1,1,34),(1,2,3),(1,3,10),(2,1,3),(2,2,9)],
    'week9': [(1,1,4),(1,2,11),(1,3,8),(2,1,5),(2,2,7)],
    'week10': [(1,1,12),(1,2,13),(1,3,32),(2,1,45),(2,2,15)],
    'week11': [(1,1,43),(1,2,30),(1,3,6),(2,1,7),(2,2,4)]
}
```

First thing is to be sure that the keys are sorted, but given the key

```
format there is an issue:
data_tmp = sorted(zip(data.keys(), data.values()))
list(data_tmp)
```

Which results in:

```
# [('week10', [(1, 1, 12), (1, 2, 13), (1, 3, 32), (2, 1, 45), (2, 2, 15)]),
#  ('week11', [(1, 1, 43), (1, 2, 30), (1, 3, 6), (2, 1, 7), (2, 2, 4)]),
#  ('week8', [(1, 1, 34), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 10), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 9)]),
#  ('week9', [(1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 11), (1, 3, 8), (2, 1, 5), (2, 2, 7)])]
```

---

So first, let's define a method which extract the week number as integer:

```
import re

def week_number(wk_string):
    tmp = [ch for ch in wk_string if ch.isdigit()]
    return int(('').join(tmp))
```

So, for example `week_number('week43') #=> 43`

---

Let's sort the data

```
data_sorted = sorted(zip([week_number(wk_string) for wk_string in data.keys()], data.values()))
list(data_sorted)

# [(8, [(1, 1, 34), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 10), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 9)]),
#  (9, [(1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 11), (1, 3, 8), (2, 1, 5), (2, 2, 7)]),
#  (10, [(1, 1, 12), (1, 2, 13), (1, 3, 32), (2, 1, 45), (2, 2, 15)]),
#  (11, [(1, 1, 43), (1, 2, 30), (1, 3, 6), (2, 1, 7), (2, 2, 4)])]
```

---

With the method in place, let's convert the data to a Numpy array of dimension `(week_number, i, j)`.

**Consider that indexing starts from 0, so take it into account.**

```
dim_w = 52
dim_i = max([e[0] for _, value in data_sorted for e in value ])
dim_i #=> 2
dim_j = max([e[1] for _, value in data_sorted for e in value ])
dim_j #=> 3
```

Initialize the array to zero then loop to fill the values:

```
import numpy as np

ary = np.zeros((52, dim_i, dim_j))

for num_week, week_data in data_sorted:
    for i, j, val in week_data:
        ary[num_week-1, i-1, j-1] = val
```

Here you can see the values for the considered weeks (8 to 12):

```
ary[7:11,:,:] # indexes starts from zero

# array([[[34.,  3., 10.],
#         [ 3.,  9.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[ 4., 11.,  8.],
#         [ 5.,  7.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[12., 13., 32.],
#         [45., 15.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[43., 30.,  6.],
#         [ 7.,  4.,  0.]]])
```

---

To get the difference between adjacent rows, just use [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and `numpy.abs` to get the absolute value:

```
diff = np.abs(np.diff(ary, axis=0))

# just to see a slice of the result:
diff[5:12,:,:]

# array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[34.,  3., 10.],
#         [ 3.,  9.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[30.,  8.,  2.],
#         [ 2.,  2.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[ 8.,  2., 24.],
#         [40.,  8.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[31., 17., 26.],
#         [38., 11.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[43., 30.,  6.],
#         [ 7.,  4.,  0.]],
# 
#        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

---

Once you get the result you can rebuild the dictionary or whatever you need.